# boost regex whitespace followed by one or more asterisk

Tags: c++, regex, boost

why does the following boost regex not return the results I am looking for (starts with 0 ore more whitespace followed by one or more asterisk)?

```
boost::regex tmpCommentRegex("(^\\s*)\\*+");

for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator vect_it =
    tmpInputStringLines.begin(); vect_it != tmpInputStringLines.end();
    ++vect_it) {

    boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> tmpMatch;
    if (boost::regex_match((*vect_it), tmpMatch, tmpCommentRegex,
        boost::match_default) == 0) {

        std::cout << "Found comment " << (*vect_it) << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "No comment" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

On the following input:

```
* Script 7
[P]%OMO      * change
[P]%QMS      * change
[T]%OMO      * change
[T]%QMM      * change
[S]%G1       * Resume
[]
```

This should read

```
Found comment * Script 7
No comment
No comment 
No comment 
No comment 
No comment 
No comment
```

Comment: `^` means beginning of input -- none of your input lines starts with whitespace.

Comment: looks fine to me, maybe you don't need to escape the backslashes?

Comment: Look at the cout "Found comment" is not part of the expression I am evaluating.

Comment: But are `[P]%OMO` part of the evaluation?

Comment: Added to my post above to show what output should be. And yes \[\w+\]% [A-Z]+ are in the expression.

Comment: If "Found comment" is not part of your input, then don't show it in what you're telling us is your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from the [documentation for regex_match](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_match.html):

> Note that the result is true only if the expression matches the **whole** of the input sequence. If you want to search for an expression somewhere within the sequence then use `regex_search`. If you want to match a prefix of the character string then use `regex_search` with the flag match_continuous set.

None of your input lines are matched by your regular expression as a whole, so the program works as expected. You should use `regex_search` to get the desired behavior.

Besides, `regex_match` and `regex_search` both return `bool` and not `int`, so testing for `== 0` is wrong.

Comment: Is there a better example besides http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_33_1/libs/regex/example/snippets/regex_search_example.cpp?

Comment: @MatthewHoggan Define "better". There is a simpler example on the bottom of http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_match.html.